# Creating SVG point symbol depending on content of attribute field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, symbology, attribute-table, svg

I have almost 300 localization of different airports with name by ICAO,
for example my column name is "ICAO" and values are "EPGD-Gdansk", "EPWA-Warsaw" "EPWM-Warsaw".

Can I create different marks to every airport, and then automaticly add saved SVG Symbol which name is same like the airport by City name?

Comment: Hi @Michal, welcome to GIS SE. I deleted the mention of Python/SQL to avoid the question from being closed. This site expects you to add a code attempt when asking for Python, see [tour]. In your case, the problem is even simpler and does not need any python, so to avoid the unpleasant experience of having your question closed, I removed this part of the question.

Answer (score 5):

No need for python or sql, simply use data driven override for the svg source. I have a point layer with a field `symbol`, containing the names of different amenities. In the data driven override, I add the path to the folder containing the svg symbols with the same name with this expression:

```
'C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.20.0/apps/qgis/svg/amenity/' || "symbol" || '.svg'
```

Replace the first part (path - `C:/Program Files...`) with your path and use forward slashes `/` - when using backslashes, they have to be double masked: `C:\\Program Files\\...`

*Each point is labeled with the content of the field `symbol` and the belonging svg (file with the same name stored in the path you set) is used as SVG marker:*
[image]

---

In your comment you make the point that the content of your fieldname does not match the filenames exactly. You have different options to compare just the letters (characters a-z and A-Z) part of both strings, therefore ignoring all numbers, whitespaces, points, underscores, hyphens and whatever else would affect the exact matching and also ignore upper/lower case variations.

To do so, convert you field content to only it's characters in lower case using this expression:

```
lower (regexp_replace ("symbol",'([^a-zA-Z]*)',''))
```

Like this, input `'46 st. Vincent Street'` will result in `'stvincentstreet'`. Now compare this to your filenames that you also reduce to just lowercase characters. You mentioned you have filenames like `st.Vincent Street` - such filenames containing points and spaces can be problematic, you should rethink that. Still, the expression below can handle this, just as a general remark.

If you have a list of all your actual filenames, you can do this in one single expression. Replace `symbol` in the second last line with your fieldname and in line 4 add the list of filenames you have: each in single quotes `'` and delimited with comma `,` as you can see in the example. Make sure to use the exact syntax, including e.g. single vs. double quotes (`'`/`"`) like in line 5:

```
map_get(
    from_json('{'  || array_to_string(
    array_foreach (
        array ('Mariott Hotel', 'st.Vincent Street'),  -- list of filenames
        '"'  || 
        lower( regexp_replace( @element,'([^a-zA-Z]*)','') ) || '":"' || 
         @element  || 
        '"'
    ))  || '}'),
    lower (regexp_replace( "symbol",'([^a-zA-Z]*)',''))
)
```

And this is what it expression will do:

[image]

You can now insert this expression above in the first expression instead of `"symbol"`. If the attribute `symbol` contains the value `34 st.Vincent Street`, then the output will be `C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.20.0/apps/qgis/svg/amenity/st.Vincent Street.svg` (or whatever path you defined).

Comment: What if I want, that This symbol will connect with values, which have same Name like them For example i have values like
123 Mariott Hotel
46 st.Vincent Street
34 st.Vincent Street
3 Mariott Hotel And few hundred more values in different names. And my SVG names are only Mariott Hotel and st.Vincent Street and rest of values but ofc without numbers before

Comment: See updated answer to address this problem.